# JTable not showing after adding to JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, border-layout

I have a JTable which shows up fine. If I place the Table in a JScrollPane it does not show anymore. Why not? I would like to add both tables each in an own JScrollPane. Here my code in which I am only trying to add a JScrollPane to the first table:

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setBounds(50, 68, 700, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(progressBar);

    JTextPane txtpnAutomotiveHmi = new JTextPane();
    txtpnAutomotiveHmi.setText("Automotive HMI");
    txtpnAutomotiveHmi.setBounds(362, 21, 205, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtpnAutomotiveHmi);


    testcase_table = new JTable();
    testcase_table.setBounds(50, 125, 350, 426);
    JScrollPane scroll_testcase = new JScrollPane(testcase_table);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scroll_testcase);

    teststep_table = new JTable();
    teststep_table.setBounds(399, 125, 350, 426);
    frame.getContentPane().add(teststep_table);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first mistake you make is this one: `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);` After that, all calls to `setBounds` are additional ones. Use appropriate `LayoutManager`'s instead and all your issues will be solved.

Comment: Why would you want to add `teststep_table` directly to your content pane instead of a `JScrollPane` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set the *null* layout. It is not the "default layout" and is not "the simplest to implement". It is actually very difficult to get right.

`JFrame` uses `BorderLayout` by default. Add `JProgressBar` with `BorderLayout.NORTH`, `JTextPane` with `BorderLayout.SOUTH` and `JScrollPane` with `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Remove all `setBounds`. The components will appear. If you need to position them in some sophisticated way instead, read about `GridBagLayout`.

Comment: While `GridBagLayout` can do a lot, many people find it difficult to use. Instead, I would consider using nested panels that can easily achieve complex layouts too. But good overall advice to use `LayoutManager`

Answer (score 0):

Define the size of the table and set the same size to scroll pane.

```
scrollPane.setSize(table.getSize());
```